# Picard group of a birational contraction

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $X,Y$ be normal projective varieties and $f:X\to Y$ be a birational contraction, i.e. a birational morphism which satisfies $f_\ast O_X=O_Y$. Then $f^\ast:\text{Pic}(Y)\to \text{Pic}(X)$ is injective, so let's just identify $\text{Pic}(Y)$ as a subspace of $\text{Pic}(X)$. Let $f_\ast:A_1(X)\to A_1(Y)$ be the corresponding morphism of Chow groups (with numerical equivalence). Let $\text{NE}(f)=\text{NE}(X)\cap \text{ker}f_\ast$, i.e. the cone of curves contracted by $f$.

**Question.** Is $\text{Pic}(Y)=\text{NE}(f)^{\perp}=(\text{ker}f_\ast)^{\perp}$ holds? If it helps, then we can tensor everything with $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Update:** Jason pointed out that this cannot be true without quotiening everything out by the numerically trivial line bundles $\text{Pic}^0$. Hence, I modified the question: is $\text{NS}(Y)\otimes\mathbb{Q}=\text{NE}(f)^{\perp}=(\text{ker}f_\ast)^{\perp}$ holds inside $\text{NS}(X)\otimes\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: No, that is not true, at least not until you form quotients of both Picard groups by their subgroups of numerically trivial line bundles.  Let $Y$ be a cone over a smooth plane cubic $C$, and let $X$ be the blowing up of the vertex.  Then $\text{Pic}^0(X)$ equals $\text{Pic}^0(C)$, and all of the line bundles parameterized by this group are numerically trivial, hence elements of $\text{NE}(f)^\perp$.  However, $\text{Pic}(Y)$ is cyclic.

Comment: @JasonStarr, Cool, that makes sense. Since I'm contemplating the intersection of line bundles with curves, I need to employ numerical equivalence instead of rational equivalence for line bundles. I will modify the question: Does it still hold if I switch the Picard group to the Neron-Severi group after tensoring everything with $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: I think you still have a problem. Suppose that $C$ is a curve with $g\geq 1$, $X$ is the cone over $C$ (wrt a very ample line bundle $H$). Let $f:X\to Y$ be the resolution given by blowing up the vertex $v\in X$ and $p:Y\to C$ the projection. If $D$ is a divisor on $S$, then $C_D=f_*(p^*D)$ is $\mathbb Q$-Cartier iff $D\sim _{\mathbb Q} \lambda H$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb R$. So assume that $O_C(D-H)$ is a non-torsion element in $Pic^0(C)$, then $p^*(D-H)\equiv _X0$ (i.e. is in ${\rm NE}(f)^\perp$) but it is not  in $f^*N^1(X)$ (as $C_D-C_H$ is not $\mathbb Q$-Cartier).

Comment: PS Since $X$ is a surface we can still pull back "numerically", however in higher dimensions this is a problem. BTW, if $X$ has klt sings and $-K_X$ is $f$-ample, then your claim is true by the base-point free theorem.

Comment: @Hacon, Sorry for the late reply; I had overlooked this question for a while. Thank you very much for your answer. Could you also explain what goes wrong in higher dimensions if we try to pull back a line bundle numerically?